# Techum of New York

Tags: halacha, shabbat, modern-times, techum, eruv-techumin

I'm wondering if anyone knows what the techum of/in NYC are?

Is Brooklyn separate from Manhattan?

What about Brooklyn to Queens?

Manhattan and the Bronx?

(I assume Staten Island is too far to be connected)

If they're separate, What are each of the techumin?

If the whole city is one techum, how far can one possibly walk?

Comment: AFAIK, the Brooklyn Bridge is short enough to be within both techumim at all points. Its span over the East River is ~490m, which is less than the 2000 amot (~1km) distance to require an eruv techumim.

Comment: FWIW, A chazzan who attended my shul on Rosh Hashanna in the 5 Towns, which is outside the NYC border, walked on Rosh Hashanna from 5 Towns to Flatbush - about 15 miles. The guy has semicha AFAIK, so I think he is aware of the rules. Never mind that he walked outside the "town limits". but he had to go through both Queens and Brooklyn. So the Techum must be quite large.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, I don't know _hilchos eruvin_ at all, alas: does what you said imply that one can walk over **any** bridge from Bk to Manh?

Comment: @DanF, there are houses all the way along that route, so I'm not surprised.

Comment: @msh210, all I know about eruvei techumim is the size of the techum. I don't know if one may cross a bridge on Shabbat, although I have heard that back in the day, Brooklyners would use the Williamsburg Bridge for tashlich.

Comment: ^Courtesy tag, @DanF

Comment: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/768879/rabbi-hershel-schachter/overview-of-techum-shabbat/

Comment: @msh210  Regarding any bridge it seems that he is saying that if the bridge is more then 2km then  you can not walk past 1 km in each direction so (can't walk over)

Comment: But from the lecture in the link i understand that it will not help since the 1 km of permitted walking tarts from ~72 Amos of the last house and a house withing 1 km will not extend the t'hum in any way

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt All that shows is you can get to the other side of the bridge, not that you can then walk for miles and miles into Manhattan. I don't see the relevance here.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Brooklyn and Manhattan are a contiguous metropolis. You could walk from the Battery to the northern edge of the Bronx and be within the same techum AFAIK.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt No, there are gaps. The east river is seemingly a gap between Brooklyn and Manhattan.

Comment: @DoubleAA, but it's not large enough to change the techum IIRC.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I don't think you get how techum works. A city being within 2000 Amot of you is not sufficient for it to be your city. If you are 1500 Amot from a city, then you can only walk 500 Amot into the city. Then you stop, right in the middle of a house if you need to. To be connected into a city, buildings must be less than 72 Amot apart.

Comment: IMSMC Rav M. Willig and Rav H. Schachter argue regarding whether one can walk between Riverdale/Bronx and Manhattan (possibly having to do with squaring off Manhattan vs. squaring of the Bronx).  Re Brooklyn and Mnahattan, see http://nefeshchaim.blogspot.com/2006/07/hilchos-techum-shabbos.html It seems implausible that Queens and Brooklyn aren't one unit.

Comment: By Googleing I've found an interesting article regarding the same topic in Lakewood. The author seems to be quite familiar with the topic and provided an e-mail. Considering the geographical proximity I suppose it's worth a try:
http://matzav.com/lakewoods-techum-shabbos-battles/

Comment: Take a look at Eruvin 5:2-3; that might help for some of the boroughs.

Comment: re Boston https://thelehrhaus.com/scholarship/modern-technology-meets-tehum-shabbat/

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah24/) from the Orthodox Union states:

> If you live in New York City, you can walk freely from Battery Park to Harlem.

I'm not sure if this really answers the question, but it does provide some insight.

Comment: Battery Park and Harlem are in the same Borough though, no?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Yes, I believe so; but I am not an expert on NYC.

Comment: As it only provides insight and not an answer it should be a comment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31390)

Comment: @sabbahillel It's a partial answer (a very small part, at that) in answering: "If the whole city is one techum, how far can one possibly walk?". Of course, the OP has assumed that the "if" part of the statement has a "true" value.

Comment: @DanF He assumed no such thing. He gave two of statements - “if they’re separate” and “if the whole city is one techum.” Nevertheless, I agree that this should be left as a partial answer rather than demoted to a comment.

Comment: @DonielF I have to admit that I have a bit of a bias, here ... I placed the bounty, so I'd like to award it to someone, if I can. Although, as stated, it's not a strong answer to the question. Where is the OP when we can use him??? Since I live in the NYC area, I wonder if I can change the bounty to my walking the distance of the techum?

Comment: @ezra If you ever decide to visit this area, you can accomplish 3 things: 1) visit 770; 2) visit me and 3) allow me to help you become an expert on NYC. Optionally, I'll add a 4th - You can join me in the 1st ever NYC "techumathon" after we get a good answer to this question!

Comment: @DanF Count me in next time I’m up there :)

Comment: @DanF - Oh now I want to go to New York... :) Ya know, when and if I go up there, I'm totally looking you up. I would return the favor, but there's not much to see here in Midland besides some oil rigs. Plus, stay far away from here; that's a good general rule. :P

Comment: @DonielF FWIW, I've enlisted a panel of 3 rabbis whom I know and trust very well. OK, 2 of them are related to each other (father / son). All 3 have lived in the NYC area, so I think they are familiar with the geography. I've challenged them to answer this question and officially rabbinically certify the idea of a future techumathon. It will be a great incentive to walk off the chulent & kishke. Stay tuned.